# how to fix this code to show content on web page?

Tags: angularjs, html, css

I am taking a course on coursera. In an exercise mentor write this code and execute this code.This code meant to show a list of food items. Even on the exercise it worked but this is not working to me. I think i made a syntax error even though i couldn't find it. Where i made mistake? Help me to find error of this code.

```
<html lang="en" ng-app="confusionApp">

<head>

    <title>Ristorante Con Fusion: Menu</title>

    <link href="../bower_components/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="../bower_components/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="../bower_components/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="styles/bootstrap-social.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="styles/mystyles.css" rel="stylesheet">

</head>
```

```
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row row-content" ng-controller="menuController as menuCtrl">
            <div class="col-xs-12">
                <ul class="media-list">
                    <li class="media" ng-repeat="dish in menuCtrl.dishes">
                        <div class="media-left media-middle">
                            <a href="#">
                                <img class="media-object img-thumbnail"
                                     ng-src="{{dish.image}}"
                                     alt="Uthappizza">
                            </a>
                        </div>
                        <div class="media-body">
                            <h2 class="media-heading">{{dish.name}}
                                <span class="label label-danger">{{dish.label}}</span>
                                <span class="badge">{{dish.price | currency}}</span>
                            </h2>
                            <p>{{dish.description}}</p>
                            <p>Comment: {{dish.comment}}</p>
                            <p>Type your comment:
                                <input type="text" ng-model="dish.comment">
                            </p>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

<script src="../bower_components/angular/angular.min.js"></script>
```

```
var app = angular.module("confusionApp", []);
app.controller("menuController", function() {
    var dishes = [
         {
           name:'Uthapizza',
           image: 'images/uthapizza.png',
           category: 'mains',
           label:'Hot',
           price:'4.99',
           description:'A unique combination of Indian Uthappam 
             (pancake) and Italian pizza, topped with Cerignola 
             olives, ripe vine cherry tomatoes, Vidalia onion, 
             Guntur chillies and Buffalo Paneer.',
           comment: ''
        },
        {
           name:'Zucchipakoda',
           image: 'images/zucchipakoda.png',
           category: 'appetizer',
           label:'',
           price:'1.99',
           description:'Deep fried Zucchini coated with mildly 
             spiced Chickpea flour batter accompanied with a 
             sweet-tangy tamarind sauce',
           comment: ''
        },
        {
           name:'Vadonut',
           image: 'images/vadonut.png',
           category: 'appetizer',
           label:'New',
           price:'1.99',
           description:'A quintessential ConFusion experience, 
             is it a vada or is it a donut?',
           comment: ''
        },
        {
           name:'ElaiCheese Cake',
           image: 'images/elaicheesecake.png',
           category: 'dessert',
           label:'',
           price:'2.99',
           description:'A delectable, semi-sweet New York Style 
             Cheese Cake, with Graham cracker crust and spiced 
             with Indian cardamoms',
           comment: ''
        }
        ];
    this.dishes = dishes;
});
```

I expect anyone found the error of my code so that i could reformat this code and use it.

Comment: Open your developer console on your browser. Add the error you see to your question.

Comment: Hey @Tonmoy , Please check my code and if it's ok as per your requirement then Accept it. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
var app = angular.module("confusionApp", []);
app.controller("menuController", function() {
    var dishes = [{
            name: 'Uthapizza',
            image: 'images/uthapizza.png',
            category: 'mains',
            label: 'Hot',
            price: '4.99',
            description: 'A unique combination of Indian Uthappam (pancake) and Italian pizza, topped with Cerignola olives, ripe vine cherry tomatoes, Vidalia onion, Guntur chillies and Buffalo Paneer.',
            comment: ''
        },
        {
            name: 'Zucchipakoda',
            image: 'images/zucchipakoda.png',
            category: 'appetizer',
            label: '',
            price: '1.99',
            description: 'Deep fried Zucchini coated with mildly spiced Chickpea flour batter accompanied with a sweet-tangy tamarind sauce',
            comment: ''
        },
        {
            name: 'Vadonut',
            image: 'images/vadonut.png',
            category: 'appetizer',
            label: 'New',
            price: '1.99',
            description: 'A quintessential ConFusion experience, is it a vada or is it a donut?',
            comment: ''
        },
        {
            name: 'ElaiCheese Cake',
            image: 'images/elaicheesecake.png',
            category: 'dessert',
            label: '',
            price: '2.99',
            description: 'A delectable, semi-sweet New York Style Cheese Cake, with Graham cracker crust and spiced with Indian cardamoms',
            comment: ''
        }
    ];
    this.dishes = dishes;
});
```

```html
<html lang="en" ng-app="confusionApp">

<head>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

    <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-social/5.1.1/bootstrap-social.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.min.js">
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row row-content" ng-controller="menuController as menuCtrl">
            <div class="col-xs-12">
                <ul class="media-list">
                    <li class="media" ng-repeat="dish in menuCtrl.dishes">
                        <div class="media-left media-middle">
                            <a href="#">
                                <img class="media-object img-thumbnail" ng-src="{{dish.image}}" alt="{{dish.name}}">
                            </a>
                        </div>
                        <div class="media-body">
                            <h2 class="media-heading">{{dish.name}}
                                <span class="label label-danger">{{dish.label}}</span>
                                <span class="badge">{{dish.price | currency}}</span>
                            </h2>
                            <p>{{dish.description}}</p>
                            <p>Comment: {{dish.comment}}</p>
                            <p>Type your comment:
                                <input type="text" ng-model="dish.comment">
                            </p>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Please check below code.
I have added some js and css and make it workable.
Please check the code and change image url accordingly.
All you need to do is make description detail in single line.

Comment: He is trying too access controller in wrong way 
<div class="row row-content" ng-controller="menuController as menuCtrl">

and also access this dishes variable in wrong way 
<li class="media" ng-repeat="dish in menuCtrl.dishes">

Comment: "Controller as" syntax is the more modern way to do things and he correctly adds the data to the `this` context with `this.dishes = dishes; `

Comment: Hi @georgeawg , I have updated my code.  All I need to do is make description detail in single line

Comment: What was broken? What was fixed?

Comment: @georgeawg, description field value of dishes array contain multiple line so I changed it in single line

Comment: @HardikMasalawala Thanks bro. I used enter for line spacing in Js object and that caused that problem. Thanks bro